# POI Data Provider Installation

Tags: fiware, fiware-poi

I'm trying to isntall [POI Data provider](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide) on my ubuntu 14. The documentation is a little bit old, but I have installed everything without problems.

When I try to test my enabler:
http://localhost/poi_dp/radial_search.php?lat=1&lon=1&category=test_poi
I obtain a empty web page and this error in the javascript console:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I obtain this when I list my process:
ps ax | grep 'postgres\|mongo\|apache2'

```
  965 ?        Ssl    0:04 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
15480 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
15482 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                                                                                              
15483 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process                                                                                                    
15484 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process                                                                                                
15485 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                                                                                       
15486 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process                                                                                           
16161 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16164 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16165 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16166 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16167 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16168 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16188 ?        S      0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
16419 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto postgres\|mongo\|apache2
```

Whe I verify the postgres sql table

```
$ psql -U gisuser poidatabase
poidatabase=> SELECT count(*) FROM fw_core;
```

I read 4 as expected.

But whe I try to verify mongo db:

```
$ mongo
> use poi_db
> db.collections
```

I only get "poi_db.collections" and not:
The db.collections command should list five POI data component collections created by the installation: fw_contact, fw_marker, fw_media, fw_relationships and fw_time.

what is the problem? any idea? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding that  db.collections returns nothing try command:

```
$ mongo
> use poi_db
> show collections
```

Answer (score 1):

These apparent problems have been corrected in the new release that has been pushed to GitHub https://github.com/Chiru/FIWARE-POIDataProvider.git . See the updated guide http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/POI_Data_Provider_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide for installation. Moreover the errors e.g. in sanity-check procedure have been corrected. (Another answer below refers to an error in sanity check.)